# In this function is (a : A) syntactic sugar for (a)?

Tags: scala, syntax, syntactic-sugar

In these implementations of curry and compose :

```
def uncurry[A,B,C] (f : (A => B => C)) : (A , B) => C =  (a , b) => f(a) (b)

def compose [A ,B , C] (f : B => C , g : A => B) : A => C = (a : A) => f(g(a))
```

In compose implementation is `(a : A)` just syntactic sugar for `(a)` as

```
def compose [A ,B , C] (f : B => C , g : A => B) : A => C = (a : A) => f(g(a))
```

compiles without issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but is the other way around: `(a)` is syntactic sugar for `(a:A)`, since the compiler can infer that `a` is of type `A`. You don't even need the parenthesis for `(a)`:

```
 def compose [A ,B , C] (f : B => C , g : A => B) : A => C = a => f(g(a))
```

Not necessarily related to the question, but for this particular case, that functionality is already available, so you can just do:

```
def compose [A ,B , C] (f : B => C , g : A => B) : A => C = f compose g
```